# Bevel causing weird creases

Tags: modeling

This is a picture in edit mode

[image]

and this is the crease plus the bevel settings

[image]

Comment: Does setting the *Limit Method* to *Angle* help?

Comment: I tried it ;( no luck

Comment: Wait actually yes! But now How can I make inward creases go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to make the topology a bit cleaner. Maybe this will help. I retopologized your mesh and gave it the modifier's settings from your screenshot. As you can see the beveled edge of the object on the right looks better.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

### Check object scale.

Modifiers are applied before object trasformations.

If your object has a non-unform scale, the bevel width, which has the same value in all direction, appears to have a non-uniform scale too.

See this cube with X scale = 5.

[image]

And see the same cube with the same modifier but with a uniform scale:

[image]