# Thicken Walls of Building without Distortion

Tags: modeling, objects, workflow

I've been designing a building in Blender 2.77a. Tried making the external walls out of scaled and altered cubes, but I had a lot of overlapping faces issues. I then went back and redid it with just planes; now the source of my question is **how can I take the shape of the walls, which are made of various sizes of planes and scale it or alter it so that the planes can be made thicker without losing the shape of the structure?** Extruding then scaling on one or multiple axis results in glitches in the mesh where the overlapping from alternate positioned planes mix up.

As a bit of information to assist possibly, I have tried doing this same building with *Archimesh* which works fine for single story simplistic buildings but crashes if making multistory, and cannot do interiors easily. When I made the walls with the solid cubes that were shaped there was so much overlap the *Boolean* tool actually glitched leaving hangover after vertices were deleted. I have never found a real way to scale or alter even slightly complex shapes without them messing up.

[image: this is the current state of the walls which need to be thickened without shape/structure loss]

Comment: Have you tried `Alt` + `S`? It scales along the normals, and assuming all your normals are pointing the right direction (`A` to select all then `Ctrl` + `N` if they're not), it should work!

Comment: i have tested and its one of the things i tried originally still results in it scaling oddly.

Comment: @Flameofshadow Try keying `A` to select everything, then `W` > _Remove doubles_. Then try my method. If that works, please consider accepting my answer. If it doesn't, consider uploading your .blend file to [Blend Exchange](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to using a *Solidify* modifier, you could scale along normals.

Key <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice until everything is selected. Key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to *Recalculate* normals. Set the *Pivot point* to *3D Cursor* (<kbd>.</kbd>). Key <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, drag your mouse around, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when you're happy. This will extrude, scale along normals, and only scale on the *X-Axis* and *Y-Axis*.

*Note that you may have to hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> between extruding before scaling.*

**Edit:**

Before doing the above steps, <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to *Object Mode*, key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to open the *Apply* menu, and select *Scale*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back to *Edit Mode*.

Here is your .blend back. To go on from where I left off, just key <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> and knock yourself out :)

[image]

Comment: scaling along normals freaks it out, i've had normals facing out and facing in and neither works correctly for scaling as it freaks out for some reason due to the faces being parallel to different axis, i do have a version of the same thing already done in cubes so its the right thickness but there is so much overlap even boolean cant get rid of a lot of it when deleted so if there is a way to fix that maybe its simpler.

Comment: @Flamesofshadow Once you remove doubles, Ctrl + N will recalculate normals. Worst case, you can manually flip normals.

Comment: normals/doubles arent really the issue because with the overlap on the other version its just two pieces that are over lapping in a + shape usually, i spend time lining it up correctly but the pieces have to be connected for when i do texturing, but obviously when i have two rectangles who are facing different directions vertesis dont line up well.   for the current one with the planes i dont get why i cant get the solidify+shrink/fatten or even just regular extrude scaling to work it just simply is not having those y parallels.

Comment: @Flamesofshadow Can you upload your .blend file to the link specified above and paste the link into your question or comment it?

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1939" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1939/)

Comment: @Flamesofshadow See my edit. If my answer helps, please consider accepting it.

Answer (score 6):

### Solidify & Shrink/Fatten

A way to give thickness to planar object is the *Solidify modifier* you can find in the *modifier tab* of the object. As you want to keep the profile even, you should enable the *Even Thickness* checkbox:

[image]

This will keep the wall straight and clean till your current topology allows.

Once the modifier has been apply, the correct way to increase the wall's thickness only on the seleced faces is to use the *Shrink/Fatten* tool you can find in the *Transform tab* of the Tooshelf or call it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> shortcut.

[image]

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> (or <kbd>S</kbd>) while ruiing the command to enable *Even Thickness* option to keep walls straight during the transformation.

Comment: Been looking for that feature for years! +1.

Comment: i tested the solidify and then shrink/fatten and it only partly works, the solidify doesnt work for any of the planes running parallel to the y axis and it also causes the right wall at the bottom of the right curve in the image (the one running along x axis leading into the curve) actually stretches across the screen when i move the mouse when doing that.

Comment: That's because your object is non uniformly scaled (modifiers effects are affected by that; see for example: [Symetrical bevel](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23149/symetrical-bevel) or http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34719/15140 ). If it suitable for your project, you should Apply the scale (shortcut: Ctrl+A in Object mode)