# Bevel not working properly

Tags: modeling, bevel

My bevel tool seems to be broken. It works normally on simple objects, but not on long objects. Look:
[image]

I want to know how to make the edge of the second image like the first image.
Ask for more details if needed

Comment: Your question is answered here: "[why are the longer edges being beveled more?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12288/why-are-the-longer-edges-being-beveled-more)" -- The answer there explains exactly what's going on. The fix is much shorter, and contained in gandalf3's comment: "Try applying the scale (`Ctrl+A` in object mode)"

Comment: See if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34719/15140

Comment: Thanks a lot @NicolaSap , now my bevel worked!